# How to get complete contact form information in Django?

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myemail password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            sender_name= form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender_email= form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])
            try:
                send_mail('New Enquiry', message, sender_email, ['my email@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            messages.success(request, "Your message has ben sent. Thank you for your interest.")

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

**But the sender's email is not displayed inside the email ,**
**I want the sender's email to be both at the (from:) and in the text of the message,**
Thanks for your help

[image contact test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpEBk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to your `message` variable

```
message = "{0} has sent you a new message from {1}:\n\n{2}".format(sender_name, sender_email, form.cleaned_data['message'])
```

Comment: Thank you, And can it be placed as an email sender for easy replied that

Comment: You can try it with `reply_to` param of `EmailMessage` class. [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)